# How to add distribution dots to ANOSIM?

Tags: boxplot, anova, jitter

Here is my code as is:

```
par(font.lab = 2)
group_colors <- c("gray92", "#B8E968", "#3585A6", "#FFC75F", "#EF5350")
plot(anosim_example, xlab = "Ranked Distances", ylab = "Stakeholder Groups", 
     main = "PERMANOVA ANOSIM Plot", col = group_colors, 
     pch = 19, cex = 1.2, font.main = 2)
axis(2, at = seq(0, 200, by = 25))
grid(lty = 1, col = "gray", yaxp = c(0, 200, 4))
abline(h = seq(0, 200, by = 25), col = "gray", lty = 3)
```

Here is the final image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxOpS.png)

How do I add dots into the ANOSIM like this boxplot?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Ylq.png)

I tried jitter, but not compatible.